# Where am I going wrong in animating when displaying and hiding widgets in the flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a list divided into two gridviews because I wanted only the first 3 items to be displayed and with a button to display more items later. I don't know if it was the right way to do it but it works for me.

But the method of showing and hiding the items is very aggressive so I managed to put the animation for the items to appear, but I am not able to make it disappear with the fade. And then q appears the first time, even if I hide and make the animation appear again, it doesn't work anymore.

I would like to know how to make this animation work correctly, and if I am on the right track this way or should everything be different.

This gif shows how the animation is at the moment.

[image: gif de test]

I put the code in the dartpad for easy viewing:

https://dartpad.dev/526a5719cae7d8be0772f1e87ef02ced

And the complete code also below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Test'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidget createState() => _MyWidget();
}

class _MyWidget extends State<MyWidget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
    );
    _animation = Tween(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 1.0,
    ).animate(_animationController);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  var _isExpanded = false;

  _toggleExpanded() {
    _animationController.forward();
    setState(() {
      _isExpanded = !_isExpanded;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        GridView.builder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            childAspectRatio: 1.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 0.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 0.0,
          ),
          itemCount: 3,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ItemCategory(
              title: "Teste $index",
              icon: Icons.apps,
              coloritem: Colors.deepPurple,
              onpressbtn: "teste $index",
            );
          },
        ),
        Visibility(
          visible: _isExpanded,
          child: FadeTransition(
            opacity: _animation,
            child: GridView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 0.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 0.0,
              ),
              itemCount: 5,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var indx = index+3;
                return ItemCategory(
                  title: "Teste $indx",
                  icon: Icons.apps,
                  coloritem: Colors.deepPurple,
                  onpressbtn: "teste $index",
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: _isExpanded
              ? Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_up)
              : Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
          tooltip: 'Open More options',
          onPressed: _toggleExpanded,
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

// These are sample items to be displayed in the gridview.
class ItemCategory extends StatelessWidget {
  ItemCategory({this.title, this.icon, this.coloritem, this.onpressbtn});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final MaterialColor coloritem;
  final String onpressbtn;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.5),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        splashColor: Colors.amber,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(
                icon,
                size: 70.0,
                color: coloritem,
              ),
              Text(title, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forward animation is working the first time because it is starting from 0 and going to 1. On subsequent times, it is still at 1, so starting the controller is going to make it immediately stop because it is starting at the end value. You can fix this either by calling `controller.reset()` or by passing the start value to `forward`, i.e. `controller.forward(from: 0)`.

To make the reverse animation work, you need to also have a method where you call `controller.reverse()`. This will cause the animation to play in reverse, so you will animate down to 0. Like `forward`, you will also need to tell the controller where to start animating from with `controller.reverse(from: 1)`.

You will run into another problem, though. If you merely set `_isExpanded` to false at the same time you call `reverse`, the fade animation will play but the collapsible panel will close, preventing you from seeing it. Instead of setting the visibility of the panel in response to a button press, have it be based on the current state of the animation. By listening to the controller for animation status changes, you can have the panel be visible if the animation value is anything other than 0.

Here are the suggested changes in action:

```dart
class _MyWidget extends State<MyWidget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationStatus _currentStatus = AnimationStatus.dismissed;
  ...

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
    )..addStatusListener((status) {
      setState(() => _currentStatus = status);
    });
    ...
  }

  ...

  _toggleExpand() {
    _animationController.forward(from: 0);
    setState(() {
      _isExpanded = true;
    });
  }
  
  _toggleCollapse() {
    _animationController.reverse(from: 1);
    _isExpanded = false;
  }

  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        ...
        Visibility(
          visible: _currentStatus != AnimationStatus.dismissed,
          ...
        ),
        IconButton(
          ...
          onPressed: _isExpanded ? _toggleCollapse : _toggleExpand,
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect explanation, thank you very much. I have already accepted your answer as correct. I only have 2 doubts if you can explain to me ... why in `..addStatusListener` is a colon used instead of one? And is it possible that the duration of the animation in reverse is different from the foward?

Comment: @BrunoDeSouzaCarvalho The double period `..` syntax in Dart is called the cascade operator. It's for stringing together multiple statements into one without changing the return value. For example, `var a = new Foo()..b = 2;` is the same as doing `var a = new Foo(); a.b = 2;`

Comment: And no, the reverse duration is not going to be different than the forward animation. It is the exact same animation, just played in reverse.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, it helped me a lot. about the duration of the animations I found that you can use `reverseDuration` in the` AnimationController` to do a different speed.

Answer (score 1):

Add `_animationController.reset()` to the `_toggleExpanded()` and use `Future.delayed` when setting the `_isExpanded` to `false`:

```
_toggleExpanded() {
    if (_isExpanded) {
      _animationController.reverse();
       Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 800), () => setState(() {
        _isExpanded = false;
       }));
    }
    else {
      _animationController.reset();
      _animationController.forward();
      setState(() {
        _isExpanded = true;
       });
    }
  }
```

Comment: I added but nothing changed. It remains the same.

Comment: I applied it but it still has the same problem, in fact I didn't realize that it solved the part of when the effect is hidden again opens with the fade, but when it is time to hide it remains without any animation.

Comment: I made a new edit. Check it out @BrunoDeSouzaCarvalho

Comment: Why use a hacky `Future.delayed` to synchronize the two effects when you can have one dependent on the other?

Comment: @Mobina Perfect, now it worked, that's right, I'm just sorry for seeing your answer after marking another one as correct, but this solution of yours also worked now. Thank you very much.